# Masstransit MaxConcurrentCalls setting on Azure being ignored

Tags: azure, masstransit

I'm having an issue with MassTransit on Azure and configuring the MaxConcurrentCalls on the bus. I have a process which demands execution of 1 message at a time, but I cannot get this to happen using the bus configuration.
For example during Bus configuration I set the following

```
busConfigurator.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1;
busConfigurator.PrefetchCount = 0;
```

After I have registered my consumer, I then send 3 messages to the endpoint immediately, and 3 consumer instances are immediately created and start processing. Snippet of the logs from Log4Net below.

I'm wondering has anyone else experienced this issue and how they may have resolved it, or have an idea of what I may be doing incorrectly. As can be seen from the logs below these messages start executing immediately, even though each one will take around 10-15 seconds to process.

```
[2017-02-03 16:48:18,410]   [DEBUG] [13]    [svcbus.Consumers.SellerPageConsumer]   [Consume]   []  [Loading page https://....... ]     
[2017-02-03 16:48:18,410]   [DEBUG] [14]    [svcbus.Consumers.SellerPageConsumer]   [Consume]   []  [Loading page https://....... ]     
[2017-02-03 16:48:18,420]   [DEBUG] [23]    [svcbus.Consumers.SellerPageConsumer]   [Consume]   []  [Loading page https://....... ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
I had a look through the Azure configuration properties.
When configuring a receive endpoint you can set MaxConcurrentCalls and PrefechCount there.
This *should* work

```
configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(host,"QueueName", re =>
{
    re.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1;
    re.PrefetchCount = 1;
    //configure consumers & other stuff here ...
});
```

**Old answer**
Not azure specific, but on RabbitMQ I set max concurrent consumers by calling UseConcurrencyLimit on the configurator object
e.g.

```
bus = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configurator =>
{
    configurator.UseConcurrencyLimit(options.MaxConcurrentConsumers);
    . . .
}
```

Is there something similar on the Azure configurator?

Comment: Sorry, nothing like that there for Azure. Just a setting as mentioned above like busConfigurator.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1.

Comment: Yep that worked, I had just downloaded the MT code and found the same. I'm not sure if this is by design or not. I'll pop an issue into the project on GitHub and see what comes out of it.